Set (or avoid) frequency range using sllurp llrp on RFID reader - Speedway R220
I am new to sllurp, as well as RFID readers. I am trying to find out if it is possible to limit to a specific frequency range with a Speedway R220 reader. I have some devices that the readers are interfering with when these are in range o the antennas (and primarily when the reader is set to full power). The devices in question operate in the 929 MHz range. From what I understand RFID readers are just under this (at the high end of their range), but they still interfere with these other wireless devices.
I've attempted setting FixedFrequencyMode, but I am not allowed to use this option as it is invalid in my region (FCC_Part_15_247).
Here is a sample of my attempt:
impinj_fixed_frequency_param = {
    'FixedFrequencyMode': 0,  # It errors as above if I set it to 1
    'ChannelListIndex': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
                         19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
}

self.factory = llrp.LLRPClientFactory(
    report_every_n_tags=1,
    antennas=(1),
    tx_power=91,
    impinj_fixed_frequency_param=impinj_fixed_frequency_param,
    reset_on_connect=True
)

